# How to say that I am asking you a common sense question?

Tags: phrases, expressions, single-word-requests

I said, "My question is of low standard". My teacher replied, "I don't know what do you mean by low standard question".

My question is how I should have said that the question is of low standard. Is low standard a wrong way to say? How I should articulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a question.

is a common way to preface asking a question.  Of course any modifier can then be added to the word "question".

> I have a strange question.
>
> I have a dumb question.
>
> I have a question that I think you can answer.

etc.

In the case of the OP, I would suggest that the most natural sounding sentence is

> I have a simple question.

Answer (score 4):

I would say "my question is simple" or "my question is trivial". Or perhaps a variation with some different synonym.

Why can you not just say "it's a common sense question"? That seems a common-sense-y approach... :)

And no, "of low standard" isn't wrong per se, but its meaning isn't strictly apparent. I don't think it's reasonably descriptive, as it's somewhat ambiguous: do you mean that it's a bad question or do you mean that it doesn't require too much thought?

Comment: It doesn't require too much thought. For example, what is valley? It is an easy question for an English speaker. But, It may be a tough question for a people like me. So, How I should ask such questions. I can't say trivial here. What I should say about such question? Or I can say, I want to ask you a basic question. What is meant by valley?

Comment: "Basic" works. I'd also qualify a bit, like "I want to ask you a basic question about English". And then maybe something like: "what does *valley* mean?". I think that would get your point across well.

Answer (score 2):

I would say,

- **My question is an easy one**

Answer (score 1):

My question is **[straightforward](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/straightforward)** —

> *adjective*
>
> uncomplicated and easy to do or understand